# How to manage height of a TableRow with ImageButtons?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am trying to have a custom keypad with TableLayout and ImageButtons. So far, I have got to this
[image]

But clearly, I am having problems removing the vertical spacing that comes between two consecutive TableRows. The relevant code is as follows:

```
        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:id="@+id/numkeypad"
                 android:orientation="vertical"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:stretchColumns="*"

                 android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                 android:visibility="visible"
                 android:background="@color/contents_text"
            >

        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >

            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/numkeypad_1"
                         android:layout_height="60dp"
                         android:layout_weight="0.33333333333333"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/k1"
                    >
            </ImageButton>
            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/numkeypad_2"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33333333333333"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/k2">
            </ImageButton>
            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/numkeypad_3"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33333333333333"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/k3">

            </ImageButton>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                      android:layout_height="60dp"
                                      android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/numkeypad_4"
                         android:layout_weight="0.33"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                         android:src="@drawable/k4"
                    >
            </ImageButton>
            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/numkeypad_5"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/k5">
            </ImageButton>

            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/numkeypad_6"
                         android:layout_weight="0.33"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="60dp"
                         android:src="@drawable/k6">

            </ImageButton>
        </TableRow>
```

Can someone point me what is causing the vertical spacing between the two TableRows and how could I remove it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `layout_weights` on the `TableRows` and the views in the `TableRows`?

Comment: Well, I did not have much idea how to remove the spacing, hence, I tried to have weights everywhere. I was just verifying if it would work.

Comment: Remove the weights, add `android:background="@null"` to all your `ImageButtons` and double check and see if that `src` image for the `ImageButtons` doesn't contain the space you see.

Comment: I did what you said, but it doesn't help. The vertical spacing is still there. http://i47.tinypic.com/2i06e0j.png

Comment: Are you sure you're not setting some margin/padding through a custom theme? Can you post one of the images used by the `ImageButtons` somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Luksprog. I am quite sure that I have not used any margin/padding anywhere. I am unaware if there are some default settings for TableLayout. http://i45.tinypic.com/wv3dia.png is the image for ImageButton 0.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17995/discussion-between-codera-purpa-and-luksprog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you see it's due to that `LayoutParams` that you use for the `ImageButtons`. The `TableLayout` and `TableRow` are widgets that impose certain constraints on their children(regarding `Layoutparams` values used). A `TableRow` in your layout should be like 
this:

```
  <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp" >

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/numkeypad_1"
                android:src="@drawable/k1" 
                android:background="@null" /> <!-- remove and possible padding from the Button drawable -->
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/numkeypad_2"
                android:src="@drawable/k2" 
                android:background="@null" />
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/numkeypad_3"
                android:src="@drawable/k3"
                android:background="@null" />
  </TableRow>
```